# DFS: Adding nodes with a certain value to a stack (java)

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, tree, depth-first-search

I have a tree. Some of the nodes in this tree have a value. I want to find the nodes that have the value and add it to a stack.

```
private Stack<Integer> dfs(Node e, Stack stack) {  

    if(e.num != 0){  
         stack.push(e.num); 
    } 

    for(Node child : e.children){ 
        dfs(child, stack); 
    } 

    return stack; 
}
```

My problem is that the relevant e.num's do not seem to be added to the stack. Instead, the stack comes back empty.

Comment: The code we see looks straightforward enough. What is the type of e.num? (e.num != 0) check might be failing.

Answer (score 0):

you should keep track of visited nodes. your code will get exception if the tree has back-edge. Moreover Java is pass-by-reference so it is better to make function void.

Comment: this tree does not have back edges

Comment: can you add Node class?